# Change Style of Apple Push Notification Programmatically

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I have implemented and configured an application with Apple Push Notification. The default alert Style of APN is "Banners", but I need to change it to "Alerts" programmatically.
I checked the UIKit.framework and did not find any options, Is it any solution to set notification style?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't. That's up to the user. Your app must obey the user's decisions for Notifications - THEY own the device, not you!